# Alert if not equal to the true value num_steps

Tags: unit-testing, machine-learning, pytest, python-unittest

I am not that good with "unittest" topic. I'd liked to create a unit test in  order to say "Hey body, this is the wrong (or right) answer because blabla!". I need to place a unit test because it took 3 MF weeks to find why the prediction in the machine learning model did not work! Hence I want to avoid that type of error in the future.

**Questions :**

1. How can I ask the code to alert me when `len(X) - len(pred_values)` is not equal to `num_step`?
2. Do I need to create a unit test file to gather all the unit tests, e.g. `unittest.py`?
3. Do we need to place the unit tests away from the main code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
The test code can alert you by means of an assertion. In your test,    you can use `self.assertEqual()`

```
self.assertEqual(len(X) - len(pred_values), num_step)
```

**2.**
Yes you would normally gather your `TestCase` classes in a module prefixed with `test_`. So if the code under test lives in a module called `foo.py`, you would place your tests in `test_foo.py`. 
Within `test_foo.py` you can create multiple `TestCase` classes that group related tests together.

**3.**
It is a good idea to separate the tests from the main code, although not mandatory. Reasons why you might want to separate the tests include (as quoted from the docs):

> - The test module can be run standalone from the command line.
> - The test code can more easily be separated from shipped code.
> - There is less temptation to change test code to fit the code it tests    without a good reason.
> - Test code should be modified much less frequently than the code it    tests.
> - Tested code can be refactored more easily.
> - Tests for modules written in C must be in separate modules anyway, so    why not be consistent?
> - If the testing strategy changes, there is no need to change the    source code.

Lots more info in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest).